# How to map a flat vector of records into an array of nested structs?

Tags: rust

I have a flat `Vec` of records

```rust
// Pseudo code

let records: Vec<Record> = [
    // Following records relate to Appointment #1
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   
    // Following records relate to Appointment #2
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },

    // Following records relate to Appointment #3
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
   { a_id: Uuid, a_working_day_id: Uuid, a_client_id: Uuid, a_start_time: NaiveTime, a_end_time: NaiveTime, s_id: Uuid, s_name: String, s_price: Decimal, s_duration: i32 },
]
```

I need to map it (somehow) to array of Rust structs

```rust
// Pseudo code

struct Appointment {
  pub id: Uuid,              // a_id
  pub working_day_id: Uuid,  // a_working_day_id
  pub client_id: Uuid,       // a_client_id
  pub start_time: NaiveTime, // a_start_time
  pub end_time: NaiveTime,   // a_end_time
  pub services: Vec<Service>
}

struct Service {
  pub id: Uuid,              // s_id
  pub name: String,          // s_name
  pub price: Decimal,        // s_price
  pub duration: i32,         // s_duration
}
```

where the final result should be like this

```rust
// cut

let result: Vec<Appointment> = vec![]; // { Appointment, Appointment, ... Appointment }

// cut
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Rust?

P.S. I would like to do this mapping manually without using additional libraries, but any example would be appreciated

Comment: What is a record in Rust? I wasn't aware that Rust had a built-in Record. Is this from an external library?

Comment: @caTS is't a pseudocode.

Comment: Just implement `impl From<Record> for Appointment` then just do: `records.into_iter().map(|r|Appointment::from(r)).collect()`

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze yes but the problem remains. How is a record different from a struct?

Comment: Yes, it's a pseudo-code. But I borrowed the name from `sqlx` database type. Where `Record` is a return type from the database.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, It seems like you trying to map `Record` to `Appointment` like 1:1. `Appointment` consists of multiple `Service`. It means that I need to iterate over all records (`Record`) to collect corresponding `Service` first and after put them inside `Appointment`.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Given that there is no definition of `Record` and how it relates to other types, it's not possible to give better answer.

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm in the same need...

Comment: @FredHors, As far as I remember, I iterated over the list of elements and compare duplications on my own. At least I didn't find any better approach

Answer (score 1):

Use iterators. For example if you have type `A` and `B` and function `fn foo<A, B>(x: A) -> B`. You could write.

```
let a: Vec<A> = vec![];

let b: Vec<B> = a.into_iter().map(foo).collect();
```

See the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) for all the other neat things you can do with iterators.

Comment: I'm unsure if I can write this code on my own. Could you please provide a working example using [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)? If you don't mind of course

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6965f4a4b11a97e9ad80d1d56e75c75c) you are.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if your example is solving my problem. You have a simple `map` function that maps one struct into another. The problem that I have is something different. I have a flat list of records that contains duplicate data (that's how the database returns values). From that data, I need to construct `Vec<Appointment>` where each `Appointment` contains `Vec<Service>` without duplicates etc.

Comment: I have no problem understanding what I need to do. The only thing that blocks me is my experience with Rust. That's why I'm asking you :)